# JavaScript: how to render data in multiple columns using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml

I have the following JavaScript code, which makes a call to an API and renders some sales data:

```
  // Get orders
  fetch(`/orders/${businessUnit}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(orders=> {
      // a Div for each order
      orders.forEach(order => {
        const element = document.createElement('div');

    element.innerHTML = `
                  <div class='orders-render'>
                  <span> ${order.buyer} </span>
                  <span> ${order.seller} </span>
                  <span> ${order.timestamp} </span>
                  </div>
              `
   
    document.querySelector('#orders-view').append(element);
  })
})
.then(orders=> {
  console.log(orders)
})
}
```

**CSS**

```
.orders-render {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

The `buyer`, `seller`, and `timestamp` data on each line is rendered very close together, as follows:

```
United States Germany 2021-07-15
China Russia 2021-07-14
Brazil Bosnia and Herzegovina 2021-07-14
```

How would I render the data such that it's in a **structured column format**, as follows?

```
United States   Germany                 2021-07-15
China           Russia                  2021-07-14
Brazil          Bosnia and Herzegovina  2021-07-14
```

Thanks!

Comment: To make a table, use [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). (Or `display: table` or `display: grid` CSS, if you want to Do It Yourself, but `<table>` is easy and available and exactly designed for this use case.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add more css to add width for each column as

```
.orders-render span{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```js
var orders = [{buyer: 'United States', seller:  'Germany', timestamp: '2021-07-15'},
{buyer: 'China', seller: 'Russia',  timestamp: '2021-07-14'},
{buyer: 'Brazil', seller: 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', timestamp: '2021-07-14'}];
orders.forEach(order => {
        const element = document.createElement('div');

    element.innerHTML = `
                  <div class='orders-render'>
                  <span> ${order.buyer} </span>
                  <span> ${order.seller} </span>
                  <span> ${order.timestamp} </span>
                  </div>
              `
   
    document.querySelector('#orders-view').append(element);
    });
```

```css
.orders-render {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.orders-render span{
display:inline-block;
width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id='orders-view'></div>
```

```css
.orders-render {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
The buyer, seller, and timestamp data on each line is rendered very close together, as follows:

United States Germany 2021-07-15
China Russia 2021-07-14
Brazil Bosnia and Herzegovina 2021-07-14
```